# Box.api 'unauthorized' error after ticket & auth?

Tags: box-api

I followed the Box.com API manual at http://developers.box.com/get-started/#authenticating but still have a problem. I'm always getting the 'unauthorized' response. Do I need to redirect the user every time to the ticket URL? Or can I in my app reuse the auth token as long as the user doesn't reject my app?

So I did: 1. get ticket 2. goto to http....auth/ url and logged in to box account 3. Got auth token 4. List folder content with auth token.

Are steps 1 and 2 repeatedly necessary (for the same box.com account)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to repeat steps 1 and 2 .  The token will last indefinitely.  But you have to include it and the api key in the header of every request you make.

Mike